AWS IAM-Policy to restrict only remote repository/branch deletion
Iam trying to write an IAM policy to restrict user on deleting branch/repo using below.But could see delete operation of branch is executed using command git push origin --delete test-delete-branch .
Correct my policy or any steps to consider to ignore only delete operation..rest codecommit operations should work.
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"codecommit:*"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:111111111111:MyDemoRepo"
},
{
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": [
"codecommit: "codecommit:DeleteBranch"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:111111111111:MyDemoRepo"
"Condition": {
"StringEqualsIfExists": {
"codecommit:References": [
"refs/heads/test-delete-branch",
]
},
"Null": {
"codecommit:References": "false"
}
}
}
]
}

Your IAM policy has a few issues that need correcting.


{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "codecommit:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:111111111111:MyDemoRepo"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:111111111111:MyDemoRepo",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "codecommit:References": "refs/heads/test-delete-branch"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}




Its not working..i could still able to delete the branch using below command.
git push origin --delete test-delete-branch

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
